# detect when UIWebView finished loading without a delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

is it possible to execute:

```
[UIWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

in a way that I know when UIWebView is finished loading the NSURL so I can proceed with further processing ? Other than using a delegate. If not what are the conditions under which the delegate will work.

Thank you for any tips/ideas

To explain further. I have this code that worked for me in a test application:

```
webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webview.delegate = self;
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

In the test app's header I had:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
UIWebView   *webview;
```

}

I'm trying to replicate this in a very complex environment that I don't fully understand. 
I don't know where to put  since it's not clear to me. The interface is defined as:

```
@interface Stream (Extension)
@end
```

and it has four more interface defined later in the header file.

In my implementation I get "undeclared identifier self"

Comment: Why don't you want to use the delegate?

Comment: That first snippet of code isn't exactly as it appears in the file is it? i.e. the webView line appearing right after the #import?

Comment: no, sorry. wrong section, now fixed.

Comment: Show more of the code where self is assigned to the delegate. What method is this in? Are you saying the ViewController interface is defined in the Stream interface?

Comment: no there is no ViewController interface anywhere, hence my problem with using delegates and the method I need to add the UIWebView to is in no particular interface implementation as far as I can tell. it sits on its own between two sets of @implementation...@end

Comment: You'll have to show more, its difficult to understand what you mean, and the code will probably be needed to comment on it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find out when the web view has finished fetching the content of the NSURL and any embedded content requests in the page if you used an NSURLProtocol to intercept the network traffic (but you would have to know in advance if the html page is going to make requests to fetch i.e. images).

But you cannot detect when the UIWebView has loaded the dom or finished displaying the page
without the delegate (out of curiosity may I know why you are asking such a question).

Comment: thanks. because I'm working with an older (and complex) code I did not originally write ... and because I'm still a noob having trouble implementing the delegate method. Is there a way to implement this in some self contained way with all the interface definitions independent of the other code. This is a one time thing. Load up the UIWebView with an NSURL, wait until it's finished loading and then access it's properties for further processing

Comment: Not sure what your question is, could you rephrase it or illustrate what you mean please. Implementing the delegate for UIWebView is pretty easy, what parts are you having problems with?

Comment: added more information to the original question on top. thank you.